# Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432` in Docker

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma

I'm working in a NX NEST+ANGULAR environment with a Docker container for NEST and Postgres. The CRUD operations work fine from the localhost to database container but I get the error if I send the request from the nest container to the database container. My docker-compose file configuration in root dir:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nest-api:
    container_name: nest-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  nestjs-crud:
```

Meanwhile the database URL in .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://admin:admin@postgres:5432/mydb?schema=public"
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . .
COPY /prisma ./prisma/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3333
EXPOSE 9229

CMD [  "npm", "run", "start:migrate:dev" ]
```

and I've configured my package.json like this: `"start:migrate:dev": "prisma migrate deploy && nx serve"`

I still can't figure out what I'm missing and where I'm doing the mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://aly.arriqaaq.com/linux-networking-bridge-iptables-and-docker/

Comment: Try from nest connect to 127.0.0.1:5432

Comment: Probably due to this: "WARNING: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: nestjs-crud"

Comment: Does `start:migrate:dev` run in the context of docker, or does it run on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep both containers in same network to allow them communicate. Update your docker-compose.yml file as below.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nest-api:
    container_name: nest-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    networks:
      - nestjs-curd

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - nestjs-crud

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  nestjs-crud:
```

Comment: I've tried this already but doesn't work. The only way I can figure out is to give the IP address instead of postgres but this will cause problems if someone else from the team runs the code.